# INDEX and MATCH for multiple DATES (Excel)

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match

maybe you can help me on this.

I need a Excel formula to lookup for all multiple events on a same day:

- Type the day you want to search
- Return several lines with the same date, but indicating the event.

So this:

```
    DATE    EVENT           SEARCH DATE HERE> 21/01
    21/01     A        
    21/01     B
    21/01     A
    21/01     A
    22/01     A
    22/01     B
    23/01     B
```

Would become this:

```
    DATE    EVENT 
    21/01     A
    21/01     B
    21/01     A
    21/01     A
```

I was trying to use this:

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF(A2:A8=$F$1,ROW(A2:A8)-1),ROW(A1)),2),"")}
```

Which works well looking for values, but not looking for dates..

Any idea why?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not use a filter instead?

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid using that because this will be used by inexperienced users. So all I want them to do is to put the date in a square and a graphic will appear to them with all the information they need.
But yeah, maybe it would be way easier to just do a dynamic table or a filter as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a filter would be best but if you want a formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/($A:$A=$D$1))*ROW($1:$1040000),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Copy over and down as many rows as wanted.  The picture the formula was copied down 8 rows.

[image]

The Aggregate function is new to Excel 2010 so any that are older than that it will not work.

Comment: Perfect, this is the formula I needed, it works pretty well!
Thank you, Scott!

Answer (score 1):

I got what you asking for simply using:

`=IF($A2=$F$1,$A2,"")`
 and
`=IF($A2=$F$1,$B2,"")`

under the date and event columns, respectively in the filtered result list.

Also, in your formula, the "if" only has 2 parameters. Is this intentional?

---

You can also filter by the following:

**Select the date and events cells**

[image]

**Click Format as Table, check My table has headers and hit OK.**
[image]
[image]

**Click on the down arrow next to the column header, and choose Filter.**
[image]

Comment: It was intentional since worked for numbers, but may not be the best practice..
Your answer is another way of thinking and worked well, even it's not the final formula I was looking for, thank you!